# TimescaleDB, how to structure a view to generate per day-of-week per month results?

Tags: timescaledb

[image: visitors heatmap]

This particular chart data are generated with map-reduce in Mongo (over a custom time-series framework).
I am now trying to migrate to timescaledb and cannot figure out a way to generate the data required for this type of chart.

My timeseries data is very simple. A timestamp and a value (visitors). I want to generate a yearly chart (heatmap) where each Day-Of-Week is aggregated on a monthly base as seen in the screenshot.

---

My current solution is not very elegant not to mention it is rather slow, taking slightly over 2sec on average to respond and my table includes redundant data (dow and month columns).

In the data-source table, I added additional columns holding the dow and month (numerical format).

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.visitors (
    ts timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
    uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    dow integer,
    month integer,
    count_in integer
);
```

I then generate a materialized view with bucket aggregation of 1 day.

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW visitors_1d
WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 day', ts) as time,
    uuid,
    dow,
    month,
    max(count_in) as visitors
from visitors
GROUP BY time, uuid, dow, month
WITH NO DATA;
```

Lastly, I use the following query to retrieve the data for a particular year

```sql
select 
    dow, 
    month,
    avg(visitors) as visitors
    from visitors_1d
where
    time >= '2020-01-01' AND time <= '2020-12-31'
    AND uuid = 'some-uuid-here'
group by month, dow
order by month, dow
```

All help is deeply appreciated.